# Validate dependant data of 4 comboboxes at once c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im learning MVVM C# with WPF and I need to validate 4 Combo Boxes at once. The logic behind is that the selections must be of the same type ad family (2 properties of the objects that populate those comboboxes). The problem is that they must be evaluated in conjunction and I have been reaching posts from this site, MSDN and even udemy courses where I haven't been able to find answer to these questions.

In first place, where should I put my evaluation code? 
Currently the code is in the ViewModel file for the window I have built. A fragment of this validation code says the following.

```
    //Temperature Check
    private void CheckTemperature()
    { 
      if (Temperature < -273.15)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("You can't use temperatures below 0ºK", "It's freezing");
        Temperature = -273.15;
      }
      else if (Temperature > 100)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Surface temperature can't be that hot", "Hotter than hell");
        Temperature = 100;
      }
      CanObtainHarm();
    }
```

And it gets executed everytime that...

```
private double _temperature;

    public double Temperature
    {
      get { return _temperature; }
      set { 
        _temperature = value;
        CheckTemperature();
        OnPropertyChanged("Temperature");
      }
    }
```

My common sense says me that this is not the place to be of this validation code.
For this example I will make it a validation rule but the case of the 4 comboboxes that must be validated and if they are not properly set, they should be left void makes me crazy.
Since I haven't found how can I validate user's ComboBox input and left it void if it is not valid, I am jumping from video to post desperately.
Additional information:
There is no button to press validation, it should be performed everytime a value of these comboboxes is changed

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/june/msdn-magazine-input-validation-enforcing-complex-business-data-rules-with-wpf) you can find a good tutorial to start from. In your case I would use IDataErrorInfo Validation or maybe BindingGroups.

Comment: Just a suggestion: please do not use `MessageBox.Show` in your code, since it is absolutely not MVVM compliant

Comment: Have you looked into BindingGroups like @II Vic suggested? It seems like they would be your best option. Otherwise, you will have to consider a solution that calls the same validation method in each of the 4 properties that the comboboxes are bound to And raise each property notification events for all 4 properties in each of the 4 property setters to indicate that there may be a change in validation due to another property change...

Answer (score 0):

i boil this task down like:

- Validate dependant data of 4 comboboxes at once c#
- when any of these 4 properties change, run some validation logic
- on property changed, if propertyName = one of the 4, run some validation logic
- INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged, switch statement, validation logic

so somewhere where we have a reference to our view model, we need to add an event handler to its PropertyChanged event, to check that the property name is one of the 4 and if so then run some validation logic.

given our view model is a dependency property on our view, i'd wire all of this up in the view's Loaded event.

ANotifyPropertyChanged - base implementation for all of our view models

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace SO60283924
{
    public abstract class ANotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var areEqual = ReferenceEquals(backingStore, newValue);
            if (areEqual)
                return;
            backingStore = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

SomeViewModel - a view model with 5 properties, 4 of which we want to validate in conjunction

```
namespace SO60283924
{
    public class SomeViewModel : ANotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string someString;
        private int someInt;
        private object someObject;
        private decimal someDecimal;
        private object somePropertyNotPartOfValidation;

        public string SomeString { get => someString; set => SetProperty(ref someString, value); }
        public int SomeInt { get => someInt; set => SetProperty(ref someInt, value); }
        public object SomeObject { get => someObject; set => SetProperty(ref someObject, value); }
        public decimal SomeDecimal { get => someDecimal; set => SetProperty(ref someDecimal, value); }
        public object SomePropertyNotPartOfValidation { get => somePropertyNotPartOfValidation; set => SetProperty(ref somePropertyNotPartOfValidation, value); }
    }
}
```

MainWindow - a view for some view model

```
<Window
    x:Class="SO60283924.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow code behind - where we add the property changed handler with the validation logic

```
using System.Windows;

namespace SO60283924
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public SomeViewModel SomeViewModel
        {
            get { return (SomeViewModel)GetValue(SomeViewModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SomeViewModelProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeViewModelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SomeViewModel), typeof(SomeViewModel), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new SomeViewModel()));
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SomeViewModel.PropertyChanged += (_, propertyChangedEventArgs) =>
            {
                switch (propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName)
                {
                    case nameof(SomeViewModel.SomeDecimal):
                    case nameof(SomeViewModel.SomeInt):
                    case nameof(SomeViewModel.SomeObject):
                    case nameof(SomeViewModel.SomeString):
                        //TODO add validation code
                        break;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

this accomplishes our goal: on property changed, if one of our 4 properties changed, run some validation logic.